# Alpaca trading "error: invalid syntax (400)"

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, trading, algorithmic-trading, alpaca

I'm having an issue running a very simple script to pull in live data data from their web socket.

I wrote a simple script to connect to the websocket and get a non descriptive error with no python exception

```
$ python3.9 bot.py 
error: invalid syntax (400)
```

bot.py

```
import traceback
from alpaca_trade_api.common import URL
from alpaca_trade_api.stream import Stream


symbol = 'BTCUSD'

ALPACA_API_KEY = "{{APIKEY}}"
ALPACA_SECRET_KEY = "{{SECRETKEY}}"

async def print_crypto_bars(t):
    print('crypto bar', t)

# Initiate Class Instance
stream = Stream(key_id=ALPACA_API_KEY,
                secret_key=ALPACA_SECRET_KEY,
                base_url=URL('https://paper-api.alpaca.markets'),
                raw_data=True)

stream.subscribe_crypto_bars(print_crypto_bars, symbol)

@stream.on_crypto_bar(symbol)
async def _(bar):
    print('@on_crypto_bar', bar)

try:
    stream.run()
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

I've found nothing online to help diagnose this with alpaca client lib

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own client for alpaca manually to disect this non-descript issue.

I ended up finding it was the symbol

was

`symbol = 'BTCUSD'`

... causing "error: invalid syntax (400)"

changed to

`symbol = 'BTC/USD'`

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved it for me. It's aggravating that the alpaca docs are not updated and still show BTCUSD...